# How should I properly go about null errors in my code?

Tags: flutter, dart, null

I'm fairly new to Flutter Mobile application framework and I'm still trying understand Darts null safety.
On line 11 I'm unsure on how to go about this error in my code.

~ Non-nullable instance field '_numberfrom' must be initialized.
Try adding an initializer expression, or a generative constructor that initializes it or mark it late.

- should I mark it late and would that be proper way  go about initializing 'numberfrom'?

---

- Line 37 I'm aswell receiving blue line on my code

Text((_numberFrom == null) ? '' : _numberFrom.toString()),
~ The operand can't be null so the condition is always false, try removing the condition, an enclosing condition, or the whole conditional statement.

Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you! I attached snippet of my code aswell, Im really looking for ideas and help to properly fix the bugs.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InM55.png)

Comment: `double? _numberFrom` and `Text(_numberFrom?.toString()??'')` may help.

Comment: just know that, `double? someValue` means `someValue` can be null.

Comment: I used the double? _numberFrom and it fixed the error! So What the line of code I believe is telling complier is that double? _numberFrom could possibly be double value or another data type correct?

Comment: `double? someValue` means we tell complier that `someValue` can be a double value or null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check `null` value, make it nullable by declaring like `int? _numberFrom;` .
Then you can use `Text((_numberFrom == null) ? '' : _numberFrom.toString()),`

How-ever, if you're declaring variable using `late`, you will get exceptions.

If you do `Text((_numberFrom == null) ? '' : _numberFrom.toString()),` it will always take spaces.

I prefer when I don't want to use default value (column/stacks..)

`if (_numberFrom != null) Text(_numberFrom.toString()),`

inside single child use `Visibilty`

```
  Visibility(
          visible: _numberFrom != null,
          child: Text(_numberFrom.toString()),
        ),
```

**Result**

`Text((_numberFrom == null) ? '' : _numberFrom.toString()),` it will always take spaces ***RedColor***.

[image: OutPut]

**Test Widget**

```
class TestCenter extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int? _numberFrom;
    int? num2;

    late int num3;

    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 100,
          color: Colors.deepPurple,
          child: Text("Top"),
        ),
        Text((_numberFrom == null) ? '' : _numberFrom.toString()),
        Text((num2 == null) ? "num2 is null" : num2.toString()),

        ///* this will will be cause errors
        // Text(
        //   (num3 == null ? "num3 is null" : num3.toString()),
        // ),

        ///* I prefer when i dont want to use default value
        if (_numberFrom != null) Text(_numberFrom.toString()),

        Visibility(
          visible: _numberFrom != null,
          child: Text(_numberFrom.toString()),
        ),
        Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 100,
          color: Colors.deepPurple,
          child: Text("Bottom >"),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow this was extremely useful! I really like how you broke it down including how use late statement in better clarification, Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`if null`](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety) operator in your `Text` widget like this:

```dart
Text(_numberFrom.toString() ?? 'default value')
```

You can check more information about null-safety [here](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)

Comment: what do you mean by utilizing the default value?  And how would I annotate ?? for _numberFrom, Thank you for your replay!